# i have a variable Xit (units of product i produced at period t) and i have to put it in LpVariable expression

Tags: pulp

I write the following expression

```
Xt = LpVariable.dicts("Quantity Produced", t, 0)
```

But it works only for the case of one product but for my problem I have to writeit for the case of multi products

Comment: Xit is a matrix that show the quantity produced of each product at each period

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to have 5 products and 5 time units, you can create a dictionary mapping a pair (product name, time unit) with the corresponsing variable.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> products = [f"prod_{i}" for i in range(1,6)]
>>> time_units = [f"t_{i}" for i in range(1,6)]
>>> vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Quantity Produced", itertools.product(products,time_units), cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0)
```

and access a variable with the pair (product, time unit)

```
>>> vars["prod_1", "t_1"]
Quantity_Produced_('prod_1',_'t_1')
```